# I want to upload the ReactJs folder in github repository but didn't Get it?

Tags: git, github, version-control, github-for-windows

Upload many time by GitHub given procedure to upload folder in repository but didn't get any solution. it only take the file have content but not their folder.

```
git in it
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin https://github.com/asadarain010/AsadPortfolio.github.io.git
git push -u origin main
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `git add README.md` on the second step, that adds to **staging** only `README.md` file. If you want to add all the files use `git add .` command instead. You can read more about [here](https://github.com/git-guides/git-add).

Answer (score 0):

Open the command prompt on your computer, and copy your project path there. Make sure the path of your folder is correct.

Once you've written the path, you will write the above line, in the command prompt as well.

```
`git init
 git add .
 git commit -m "description"
 git remote add origin "**GitHub given link**"
 git branch -M main
 git push -u origin main`
```

Try the above way, if you still don't properly understand, you can directly upload files on GitHub. In your repository, there is a button called **Add files**. Click on that button, you'll see another button **upload files**. Tap on that and select all files you want to upload.